# First Flutter App stuck at “Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'… ” in Llnux Mint

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm getting the following error while running my first flutter app in the terminal

```
Launching lib/main.dart on vivo 1802 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)
```

I already tried downloading the gradle distribution separately and copy pasting it in my project's gradle wrapper and restarting android studio but it still doesn't resolve the issue.

I'm using Linux Mint 19.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, read the description of the tags that you applied. You'd also have to provide a [mcve] in order to make your question on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have an **internet connection**.When running an app for the first time, gradle needs to download some additional content
2. Check your connection to your virtual phone or your phone well. Make sure it doesn't disconnect while you are running the app

Comment: Yes, I have continuous stable internet connection but it still keeps running never finishing up!

Answer (score 0):

Before starting this building process, make sure:

1. USB debugging is enabled on your phone,
2. No app is currently running (and you are on your home screen),

While running your app for the first time on a phone, your phone will get a pop-up asking you to allow the installation of apps via USB.

Click 'allow' on it.

Not clicking 'allow' or simply ignoring it will make it seem like the build process is never-ending.